# How do i get image from imageUrl in imageView

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, dataadapter

How can i get image from image url in image view.
My imageUrl is coming from databaseadapter.

 In Fields class LocationImage dataype is string but in **setBackgroundResource** method it is asking for int value as parameter. LocationImage url is getting from database, so that i've taken that as string variable.

**code lines are here.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindPlaces extends ListActivity{

    private SQLiteDatabase DbLoc;
    ListView lv;
    int val;
    private ArrayList<Fields> results = new ArrayList<Fields>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.places);
        getallLocs();
        setListAdapter(new StudentListAdapter(this,  val, results));
    }

    class StudentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fields>{
        private ArrayList<Fields> locationDetails;
        private Context mContext;

        public StudentListAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Fields> results) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, results);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            System.out.println("Constructor StudentList Adapter...");
            this.locationDetails = results;
            mContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return results.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Fields getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return locationDetails.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){
                LayoutInflater vl = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vl.inflate(R.layout.placeslist, null);
            }
            Fields o = results.get(position);

            if (o != null) {
                TextView iv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView tv_sNo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext1);
                ImageView tv_Image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.Locimage);

                iv.setText(o.getLocationName());                            
                //tv_sNo.setText("Status: "+ o.getOrderStatus());
                tv_sNo.setText(o.getLocationImage());   
                tv_Image.setBackgroundResource(o.getLocationImage());
            }
            DbLoc.close();
                            return v;
        }       
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView Locationname;
        ImageView Locationimage;
    }
    private void getallLocs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(
                    this.getApplicationContext());
            DbLoc = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = DbLoc.rawQuery("SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.LocationName+ " , " + DatabaseHelper.LocationImage + " FROM "
                    + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONTABLE , null);
            System.out.println("SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.LocationLang+" , "+DatabaseHelper.LocationLat+" , "+ DatabaseHelper.LocationName
                    + " ," + DatabaseHelper.LocationImage + " FROM "
                    + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONTABLE );
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String LocationName= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LocationName"));
                        String Mobile = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("LocationImage"));
                        Fields p = new Fields(LocationName, Mobile);
                        results.add(p);

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            "Could not create or Open the database");
        } 
                }
}
```

Comment: Is this image was in sdcard or in the resource folder like in drawable folder? could show me the path you retrieve from the database?

Comment: what u got fromm o.getLocationImage() in ur code.is url or lese

Comment: url is like  [link](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f80674989557a35b0fec1fdc21ecbcc4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG) I'm storing image url's in database, in display i want to display directly from url.. is this righty way doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u got image url use the below code to set the image from url to imageview

```
Bitmap mbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL("urlname").openStream());
Imageview_ref.setImageBitmap(mbmp);
```

Comment: Could you please suggest me the best way of showing image in my application. I'm getting image url's from database from there i want to show image. For this i need to access internet right? is this right way doing?

Comment: @atluriajith: s u needinternet conncetion and take taht uses permission in manifest file.and follow the above code

Comment: If we use internet for load of every image. Then it will consume battery.

Comment: yes.obviously.But with out internet connection u did not display the image from url

Comment: oh! then how can I use my image url's to display image?

Comment: @Pinki: thanks for your answer got it.. But is there any other way to work with URLs?

Comment: @ atluriajith:I think this is better way